# Python framework choice

Tags: android, python, ios, django

I know this is a bit off topic, but I really needed some help regarding this.

I am new to Python. I'm trying to build my next project (a dictionary web app which will have both iOS and android app as well) for myself in Python. I've done some research and listed out some promising frameworks.

- django
- pylons (pyramid + repoze.bfg)
- tornado
- CherryPy
- pyjamas
- flask
- web.py

etc

But while django is great, it was originally built for newspaper like sites project building. Im stuck with choice making for dictionary like web application which will have to provide RESTful web service api for mobile request handling.

So anyone can you please help in pointing out which framework is the best choice for this type of web app. I think I should go with django. Or should I go with native python coding? Any suggestions will be great.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Django*'s strength is in it's ORM, huge documentation, and the thousands of reusable applications. The problem with those reusable apps is that the majority is written following *Django*'s MVC design, and as you need a web service, and not a website or web application, most of those apps will be almost useless for you.

On the other hand, there is *Django-REST-Framework*, extending *Django* itself, which is pretty good, and it's declarative API feels as if it was part of *Django* itself. For simple cases just a couple lines of code could produce you a complete CRUD API following REST conventions, generating beautiful URLs, out-of-the box support for multiple authentication mechanisms, etc. but it could be an overkill to pick *Django* just because of that, especially if you do not wish to use it's ORM.

*Flask* on the other hand is pretty lightweight, and it's not an MVC-only framework, so in combination with *Flask-RESTful*, I think it would be an ideal tool for writing REST services.

So a conclusion would be that *Django* provides the best out-of-the-box experience, but *Flask*'s simplicity and size is too compelling to ignore it.

Answer (score 2):

Go with Django, ignore its entire templating system(used to generate web pages) and use Django-Tastypie for REST service. Easy to learn and set-up is instant.

Comment: thanx want some more opinions before kickstarting myself into this.

Comment: Having used both, I would recommend going for Django-rest-framework over Tastypie. Its a lot more consistent with Django's overall style - model serializers work very similarly to Django's model forms, and the generic API views work very similarly to Django's generic views.